# Multiple Inline stylesheets

Tags: reactjs, typescript

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fcijx.png)I am using React, Typescript and Styled components. Everything looks fine but I am seeing multiple styles tag under my head tag. I would like to know why it is creating multiple styles tag and is there any way to combine all styletags into one.

For example , I am creating a dropdown in a loop and it has 3 values and it generates 3 style tag under my head tag

Thanks all

Comment: Please show some code to demostrate the issue. Without code, it's anyone's guess. You'll get maximum engagement if you provide repro in codesandbox, stackblitz or similar.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand, I believe this is expected behavior assuming you're utilizing style partials for each component. React (and other front end frameworks like Angular) is importing the styles that apply to the current view. It does this by importing them individually as the page renders different views.

This isn't always ideal, though. I often create CSS partials in a global styles folder if I want to share styles across components. The only styles I put in the component specific CSS file are styles that are 100% specific to that component and I don't ever want to share.

You could also always create a shared CSS file that you import once - ie - `dropdown.css` (or .scss etc if you're using a pre-processor) and delete the react component specific CSS files that you will be replacing with this new global version. The downside being that whatever CSS you have in there will always be imported even if the dropdown isn't being rendered or viewed.